# Getting error "detox_1.web is not a function"

Tags: detox

I'm getting an error trying to use `web()`.  I'm on Detox 18.22.1 and am importing it into my TS test script like this:

```
import {by, device, element, expect, waitFor, web} from 'detox';
```

In my class, I declare a var for the web view and assign it in the constructor, following the example at https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/39107894e974a68f634de08481697a144b53dbb3/detox/test/types/detox-global-tests.ts:

```
private webView: Detox.WebViewElement;

<...later, in the constructor...>

this.webView = web(by.id('Web View'));
```

When I run my test, I'm getting this error:

```
  ● Login/Create Account E2E suite › logs in with Google

    TypeError: detox_1.web is not a function

      36 |     this.showHidePwButton = element(by.id('LoginScreen-Password-ShowHideButton'));
      37 |     this.username = element(by.id('LoginScreen-Username'));
    > 38 |     this.webView = web(by.id('Web View'));
         |                    ^

      at new LoginPage (src/pages/LoginPage.ts:38:20)
      at _callee3$ (tests/LoginCreateAccount.e2e.ts:51:17)
      at tryCatch (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:274:22)
      at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
      at tryCatch (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
      at invoke (../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:20)
      at ../node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:170:11
      at tryCallTwo (../node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
      at doResolve (../node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
```

Has anyone seen this before?  I'm not too sure how to debug it; any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you manage to call web function? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @TomásWonderfurt For me the issue was that I was importing it, removing the import fixed it (now got the issue that it doesn't work on iOS)

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports, for me that was the issue, you don't need to do:

`import { web } from "detox"`

you can use it directly as detox puts it in the scope. That being said, it seems to work only on iOS